# php-gtk issues (combobox, beep and spinbutton)

Tags: php-gtk

I recently moved a complete application from PHP5.1 + GTK2.6 + Libglade to PHP5.6 + GTK2.24 + GTKBuilder. I rebuild all glade files for GTKBuilder and fixed some PHP issues. Application starts and all windows open as expected. But I am having some troubles with a few things.

First is the quick jump-to function in a combobox. When I press the 'p', I assume to jump to 'potatoes', for example. But since the upgrade it doesn't. I have read that this might be a bug in GTK. Maybe anybody here has a workaround? I might be able to build a filter/jump function myself, but maybe there is a solution.

Second is that the GDK::BEEP() function isn't beeping, and isn't giving me an error. Any ideas here?

Third and last (for now) is that spinbuttons don't act as supposed. When I fill them it enabled both the up and down button, but the buttons don't respond. So if I press up, the value doesn't get increased.

Hoping to find someone here who might be able to help, since I'm getting the feeling that the PHP-GTK community isn't one of the biggest around. ;)

Cheers!

Comment: its really cool to see that you're using php-gtk for development. i tried doing it years back but didn't move forward. it would be interesting to see what you developed so far. I've been meaning to develop on it and tried looking at http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/reference.php but there wasn't a whole lot and it seemed minimal. have you thought of using QT? https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.5/creator-overview.html ? http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/GTK_vs_Qt

Comment: I build an application for a semi-webshop based store. It has over 200 diferent windows (all in glade) and connects to a MySQL server.  It utilizes barcode scanners, labelprinters, A4 printers and stuff like that.

I dont know QT, I used (PHP-)GTK cause I know PHP and because I once got (by accident) got hold of a few lines of example code. 

Now the application needs to connect with a MSSQL 2012 server, so I had to upgrade to a new PHP version. With that came the new GTK lib and the problems mentioned above.

Comment: Aparently the spinbutton thing has something to with the increments. When I manualy set these it works. Is there any way to set these in the glade file, or perhaps even in the gtkrc file?